# How to plot the function f(x) so that one part be a ticker line than another depending on the value x?

Tags: function, plot, wolfram-mathematica, line, thickness

How to plot the function f(x) so that one part be a ticker line than another depending on the value x? (Curve is efficient frontier - portfolio optimization)

Comment: Combine several plots using Show. Choose the range of x for each Plot. Set the line width for the plot you want. You may need to include a PlotRange with the first plot so that Show will include the full range even though each plot only covers part of the range

Comment: See this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28202/121

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_] := x^2;
Show[
  Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 4}}], 
  Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.02]]
]
```